# Comparison of collection datatypes in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

Does anyone know of a good overview of the different C# collection types? I am looking for something showing which basic operations such as `Add`, `Remove`, `RemoveLast` etc. are supported, and giving the relative performance.

It would be particularly interesting for the various generic classes - and even better if it showed eg. if there is a difference in performance between a `List<T>` where `T` is a class and one where `T` is a struct.

A start would be a nice cheat-sheet for the abstract data structures, comparing Linked Lists, Hash Tables etc. etc. Thanks!

Comment: Requests for tutorials etc. are not considered good questions for SO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following content was originally taken from MSDN http://xbox.create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=123&filename=DataStructures_CheatSheet.doc (but the link has since died).

[image: Complexity table]

As in the image above, the content was originally provided as a table (which StackOverflow doesn't support).

Given an image isn't easily indexed below is a somewhat crude programmatic conversion of the information to lists:

## Array

- **add to end:** `O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(n)`
- **insert at middle:** `O(n)`
- **remove from middle:** `O(n)`
- **Random Access:** `O(1)`
- **In-order Access:** `O(1)`
- **Search for specific element:** `O(n)`
- **Notes:** Most efficient use of memory; use in cases where data size is fixed.

## List

- **add to end:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `O(n)`
- **remove from middle:** `O(n)`
- **Random Access:** `O(1)`
- **In-order Access:** `O(1)`
- **Search for specific element:** `O(n)`
- **Notes:** Implementation is optimized for speed. In many cases, List will be the best choice.

## Collection

- **add to end:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `O(n)`
- **remove from middle:** `O(n)`
- **Random Access:** `O(1)`
- **In-order Access:** `O(1)`
- **Search for specific element:** `O(n)`
- **Notes:** List is a better choice, unless publicly exposed as API.

## LinkedList

- **add to end:** `O(1)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `O(1)`
- **remove from middle:** `O(1)`
- **Random Access:** `O(n)`
- **In-order Access:** `O(1)`
- **Search for specific element:** `O(n)`
- **Notes:** Many operations are fast, but watch out for cache coherency.

## Stack

- **add to end:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `N/A`
- **remove from middle:** `N/A`
- **Random Access:** `N/A`
- **In-order Access:** `N/A`
- **Search for specific element:** `N/A`
- **Notes:** Shouldn't be selected for performance reasons, but algorithmic ones.

## Queue

- **add to end:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `N/A`
- **remove from middle:** `N/A`
- **Random Access:** `N/A`
- **In-order Access:** `N/A`
- **Search for specific element:** `N/A`
- **Notes:** Shouldn't be selected for performance reasons, but algorithmic ones.

## Dictionary

- **add to end:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from end:** `O(1)`
- **insert at middle:** `best case O(1); worst case O(n)`
- **remove from middle:** `O(1)`
- **Random Access:** `O(1)*`
- **In-order Access:** `O(1)*`
- **Search for specific element:** `O(1)`
- **Notes:** Although in-order access time is constant time, it is usually slower than other structures due to the over-head of looking up the key.

Comment: Hey Guys, looks like that link no longer works.  Does anyone know of a different location for that document / have a copy available anywhere?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I've updated the link for you.

Comment: Hm... Why is the complexity of adding an element to the end of a `Stack<T>`/`Queue<T>` greater than for `LinkedList<T>`? This doesn't make sense. Isn't a `Stack<T>`/`Queue<T>` a `LinkedList<T>` under the hood?

Comment: @Abbondanza No, they're both implemented using an array buffer.
`Stack is implemented as a circular buffer.`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx

`As elements are added to a Queue<T>, the capacity is automatically increased as required by reallocating the internal array.`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Comment: @BenjaminDobell Interesting. Do you have any idea why the would favour an array over a `LinkedList<T>`? After all, a `Stack<T>` does not require random access.

Comment: Linked lists are beneficial if you want to insert into the middle of a collection (as you avoid reshuffling memory locations). However, neither a stack or a queue allows insertion in the middle of the collection. A stack only allows insertion and removal on one end, hence an array can be efficiently used, a pop is as simple as decrementing the pointer or index to top of the stack. The same is true of a queue, except you can use two pointers (or indexes), one for either end, and then wrap around as needed. This is quite a bit cheaper than creating and deleting new "link objects".

Comment: Link no longer works.

Comment: @sotn I've replaced the link with inline content so the issue doesn't occur again.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a cheat sheet but it is a good place to start learning:  [Collection Classes (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx).

**Edit:** I would look specifically at this related section: [Selecting a Collection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc79sx1.aspx)  .

> Be sure to choose your
>   System.Collections class carefully.
>   Using the wrong type can restrict your
>   use of the collection.

Comment: This is great, as it runs through all the different collections. It includes many more collection types than the cheatsheet on creators.xna.com mentioned in the other answer.